# $QR$ Decomposition Inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

For $QR$ Decomposition (of an $n$ by $n$ matrix), since $A = QR$, where $A$ is a matrix, $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $R$ is an upper triangular matrix, does this mean that $AR^{-1}=Q$?

And if the above statement is true, does that then mean that $A^{-1}=R^{-1}Q^T$?

I'm basing the second statement off a formula I learned in class, where $AG=U$ and $A^{-1}=IGU$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is invertible, then yes, since $A=QR$, you know that both $Q$ and $R$ are invertible. Therefore, $A^{-1} = R^{-1}Q^{-1}$, and since $QQ^T=I$, you know that $Q^{-1} = Q^T$, so $$A^{-1} = R^{-1}Q^T$$